# How can I fix the error instance of class name?

Tags: flutter, dart, overriding, tostring

Can someone tell me how I can fix the error instance of class name?

Answer (score 0):

```
return placeName ?? '';
```

you just need to handle if its null

Answer (score 0):

Type String? means it has to have a string or null in variable of this type So the solution is to change type to String and add required keyword to named parameter in constructor.
Try this might work...

Answer (score 0):

```
//'A value of type 'String?' can't be returned from the method 'toString' because it has a return type of 'String'
```

showing this because you've to handle null exception there. do `placeNmae?`
or

```
if (placeName != null) {
    return placeName;
  //2
  } else {
    codeExceptionsomething();
  }
}
```